# How to handle a user's profile fields privacy?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a user table which has all details like username, email id, birth date, contact no. A user has friends and these friends may belong to certain groups like for e.g close friends, family, colleagues which user has created. A friend may belong to one group or many groups or none of the groups at all.

I need to set a certain privacy related to the attributes of the user table for friends or group of friends. Like for e.g. my group of family can only view my birth date or colleagues can view only my email id but no other details like birth date or contact number.

How can I achieve this privacy?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a very broad questions, I'm not sure what is the problem. How about issuing different queries depending on the group?

Comment: Get a database that supports Row Security and Column Security

Answer (score 1):

Having a separate table for every "special" attribute, could lead you to have a lot of tables. On the other hand, you can use the entity-attribute-value model. This way you will have one table for users, one table for all the user's attributes, and one table for the values associated to an specific user and his attributes.

### User

id
idGroup

### Attribute

id
description

### Value (User-Atribute)

idUser
idAttribute
value

In addition, you can relate the attribute table and the group table. By relating these two tables you can specify which attributes will be visible for each group. Don't forget to relate the user table and the group table.

### Group

id
description

### Access (Group-Attribute)

idGroup
idAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you try to handle that logic on the code, instead of the database? It seems that this is related to business logic instead of the actual data model.

If you want to go forward with this approach have you considered having the private data in a separate table?

Comment: No. I have all the user information in one table only. I was planning to keep a separate table having a user id, the field whose privacy needs to be defined and a list of user id's to whom this field is visible. But This will create a huge table with lots of redundancy.